# How to make the <a> and <li> tags be same dimensions as <ul> for Suckerfish dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, suckerfish

I am using a Suckerfish dropdown menu with the following structure and when I inspect the HTML using Chrome's developer tools I find that the  and respective  tag have their own dimensions from the  tag. This is problematic because this is in effect causing the  to be slightly larger than my other buttons on my page. Here is a screenshot of what I mean: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9191/Screenshots/lsuf.png

As you can see Button 3 is larger than the other buttons. Ideally I would like to make Button 3 the same size as the others.

Here is the markup:

```
<ul id="suckerfish">
<li id="main"><a href="#">Button 3</a>
    <ul id="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Menu Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about CSS? I don't see why one button would be larger than others.

Comment: Looks like extra padding in the CSS. Can ypu show the CSS for the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have a 'active' class for the third button with extra padding.

Comment: that doesn't seem to do the trick. I've literally tried everything. For some reason this "Suckerfish" menu is producing 1px I can't find for the life of me!

Answer (score 0):

@brian start with using a reset css file

I use this one http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

if you are still having problems (which I doubt) just let me know